# Installing security patch for MS SQL Server fails and kills server instance

Tags: sql-server

Running SQL Server Express 2017 on Windows 10 Professional on my laptop. Everything's fine, until Windows, or I, try to install update [KB4505224](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58483). It failed and killed the server instance, meaning I couldn't connect to it anymore with SSMS and I couldn't start the service.

Having read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19538089/101606), I uninstalled and then reinstalled, this time changing the account name for the SQL Server database engine from `NT Service\MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` to `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE`, as I'm only using it locally on my laptop, it doesn't need to serve anything to any other machine.

Then I ran the update again. It failed again. It said:

```
Action required:
Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.

Feature failure reason:
An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.

Error details:
§ Error installing SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
Error code: 0x851A001A
Visit [some link] to get help on troubleshooting.
```

(That link isn't helpful, or perhaps I'm misled by all the commercial messages there.)

The last lines in the log, starting just before the first errors appear:

```
2019-07-29 20:50:56.02 spid6s      Uploading data collector package from disk: c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Install\SqlTraceCollect.dtsx
2019-07-29 20:50:56.02 spid6s      Error: 2775, Severity: 17, State: 12.
2019-07-29 20:50:56.02 spid6s      The code page 65001 is not supported by the server.
2019-07-29 20:50:56.02 spid6s      Error: 912, Severity: 21, State: 2.
2019-07-29 20:50:56.02 spid6s      Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered error 200, state 7, severity 25. This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to completion.
2019-07-29 20:50:56.02 spid6s      Error: 3417, Severity: 21, State: 3.
2019-07-29 20:50:56.02 spid6s      Cannot recover the master database. SQL Server is unable to run. Restore master from a full backup, repair it, or rebuild it. For more information about how to rebuild the master database, see SQL Server Books Online.
2019-07-29 20:50:56.02 spid6s      SQL Server shutdown has been initiated
2019-07-29 20:50:56.02 spid6s      SQL Trace was stopped due to server shutdown. Trace ID = '1'. This is an informational message only; no user action is required.
```

I'm not an expert at all, but I assume it first fails because code page 65001 is not supported, because of that it can't update the master database, it's taken offline and with it downs the server instance. Please do CMIIW.

1. How can I install SQL Server Express so that it has a code page that doesn't crash the patch, and does support UTF-8? ([65001 *is* UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629437/is-codepage-65001-and-utf-8-the-same-thing), isn't it? I do need this. The data's all UTF-8).
2. Can I let Windows defer just this patch, but update everything else as normal? I think I don't need the patch, it's just a local engine for some OEM-software I'm running, it's pretty much always behind a firewall and not visible by other machines.

Answer (score 0):

Googling "sql server express 2017 code page 65001 not supported by the server" lead to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217762/186591) on StackExchange, where a tick box for "Beta: UTF-8 support" under Regional Settings / Management / System Locale should be off. So to make things clear:

1. Installing the patch failed, server instance will not start, master database can't be reached.
2. turn tick box off
3. re-install patch.

didn't help. Then:

3. uninstall SQL Server
4. Reinstall SQL Server, tick box still off.
5. Let Windows install patch.

That worked.